# Javascript Unrecognized expression in tutorial code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of javascript that looks like this:

```
prompt = if $(this).has("option[value=]").size() then $(this).find("option[value=]") else $("<option value=\"\">").text("Select a value")
```

This raises the following error in Firebug:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[value=]
```

I have referenced a tutorial that uses this exact code and it seemed to be working fine there.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

[Link to tutorial](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2013/12/come-implementare-in-rails-4-delle-dropdown-dipendenti-con-script-jquery-non-intrusivo/)

*PS Javascript is not really my forte.

Comment: You need to provide an RHS - `value=<something>` for the expression to be valid.

Comment: That code makes no sense. What are you trying to do? It looks like you are trying to assign prompt to the return value of a poorly formed if else block.

Comment: This looks like it's pseudocode: you're probably meant to write the real code as part of the tutorial.

Comment: Also window.prompt is a built-in method. Pls give a link to the tutorial

Comment: `size()` has been deprecated for awhile, so that is an older script too.

Comment: @mplungjan , I have added a link to the tutorial.

Comment: @epascarello , what function has replaced size()

Comment: Did you change the `?:` operator to if-then-else ? In the tutorial I see the former.  These are not the same in JS.  if-then-else does not return a value that can be assigned to a variable.  the `?:` operator returns a value.

Comment: I did remove the ?: as it was returning an Unexpected ':' error. Might be because I converted the js to coffeescript? @Paul . Thanks for the insight!

Comment: I tried Coffeescript but it gave me acid reflux.

Comment: I do not see any of your code in the link you gave. size() and length are interchangeable in jQuery